# Unable to see an array's content

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, fetch

I have a database that contains things like "title, "color", and so on, and I want to display these informations in a webpage.
But, for some unknown reason, nothing won't appear, not even an error, which makes me totally lost.

I use this to put everything I need into an array :

```
<?php 
try{
$req = $db ->prepare("SELECT titre, couleur, categorie, img_url, prix, type FROM articles WHERE id = 9");
$article = $req ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e;
exit();
}
?>
```

My connection to the database is successful, but I can't even see my array's content even if I use the

```
<pre> <?php print_r($array) ?> </pre>
```

technique. I'm basing my current code from a working one, and I can't notice what I did wrong... 
Thank you in advance !

Comment: maybe returning the $article (the array) will work, tried printing $article on php page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: wouldn't it be `print_r($article)`? you're not fetching/defining `$array`.

Comment: Consult http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: Instead of `catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e;
exit();
}` use `catch(PDOException $e){
        $e->getMessage();
    }`  for the real error. Also add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, see if any errors come of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about some executing between the preparation and the fetching? like this:

```
$req->execute();
```

Also i think you want to print the array where you fetched your data in like this:

```
<pre> <?php print_r($article) ?> </pre>
```

So all in all your code should look something like this:

```
<?php 

    try{
        $req = $db->prepare("SELECT titre, couleur, categorie, img_url, prix, type FROM articles WHERE id = 9");
        $req->execute();
        $article = $req ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } catch(PDOException $e) { 
        $e->getMessage();

    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($article);
    echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: That was one huge mistake ! Thank you for that !
Still it doesn't show anything with this new code :

<?php 
try{
    $req = $db ->prepare("SELECT titre, couleur, categorie, img_url, prix, type FROM articles WHERE id = 9");
    $article = $req ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $req -> execute();


}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Erreur de connexion à la base de donnée, merci de ressayer plus tard';
    exit();
}



?>

Comment: @Jaeger Maybe you want to execute the query first and then fetch the data :D?!

Comment: @Jaeger Sry made a mistake! It has to be `$req` and not `$db`. Just copy the code again and test it!

Comment: @jaeger,first change line $db->execute(); to $req->execute.for your understanding, you have to execute first then fetch assoc array , see full documentation http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond, my connection is not the best ever. I actually used $req instead of $db (which showed my an error) however it still doesn't show my anything...

Comment: @Jaeger Put: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after your connection an see what error you get

Comment: Problem solved, maybe I'm too tired for this sh#t but I interverted some elements in my code, i fixed it all and it worked... So tired about my self right now, but thank you guys anyway !